# Format text file linux

Tags: linux, awk

I have a tabular file. I want to add blank space after match in column 4.

Input File:

```
seq1 5 15 ID1 
seq1 20 34 ID1  
seq1 50 48 ID2  
seq1 45 36 ID2  
seq1 55 75 ID3  
seq1 80 84 ID3 
seq2 17 20 ID5  
seq2 30 48 ID7  
seq2 55 66 ID7
seq3 27 40 ID9
```

Output File:

```
seq1 5 15 ID1   
seq1 20 34 ID1    

seq1 50 48 ID2  
seq1 45 36 ID2  

seq1 55 75 ID3  
seq1 80 84 ID3 

seq2 17 20 ID5  

seq2 30 48 ID7    
seq2 55 66 ID7  

seq3 27 40 ID9
```

I have tried using different `awk` oneliners but ended with 3 spaces within blank line. I want only one space blank line between blocks.

Here is my code:

```
awk '{if(NR > 1 && $4 != prev_rec){printf "\n";} prev_rec=$4; print $0}' File
```

Comment: Give us example input and output.

Comment: Are the empty lines already part of the input file? If so, it would be enough to skip empty lines.

Comment: How do the lines in your input "match"?

Comment: My version leaves the space at the end of line intact.  Its not moved to the next line. If you like them removed see my updated post using  `$1=$1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if the 4th field changes, you want to print an extra line:

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && $4!=stored {print""} {stored=$4}1' a
seq1 5 15 ID1
seq1 20 34 ID1

seq1 50 48 ID2
seq1 45 36 ID2

seq1 55 75 ID3
seq1 80 84 ID3

seq2 17 20 ID5

seq2 30 48 ID7
seq2 55 66 ID7

seq3 27 40 ID9
```

This is in fact an "idiomatication" (if this word exists :D) of your current code, that by the way works fine to me:

- The `{ }` around everything can be omitted.
- `if (NR > 1 && $4 != prev_rec) {}` can be also written as `NR>1 && $4 != prev_rec {}`.
- `{printf "\n";}` can be written as `{print ""}`.
- `print $0` can be compacted into just `print` or even `1`, which evaluates to True and triggers the `awk` default behaviour: print the current line.

Finally, note I considered a clean input, whereas yours has some trailing spaces. To clean it, you can use this sed: `sed -i 's/\s*$//' file`.

Comment: The code still add 3 spaces in blank line. When I go to blank line in editor cursor moves 3 times and then moves onto next block.

Comment: this is probably because your original input contains some trailing spaces. Clarify if this is the desired output or not

Comment: The original input doesnt have any trailing spaces. The required output is a only one space blank line between blocks.

Comment: Yes it does, check the revision number 3 and see the spaces: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28481377/revisions

Comment: Yes you were right. The input has spaces at the end of each line. How do i remove all trailing spaces in one go?

Comment: @user3573959 I normally do `sed -i 's/\s*$//' file`. This removes all of them in-place.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk '{print $0($4!=f?"":RS)} {f=$4}' file
seq1 5 15 ID1
seq1 20 34 ID1

seq1 50 48 ID2
seq1 45 36 ID2

seq1 55 75 ID3
seq1 80 84 ID3

seq2 17 20 ID5
seq2 30 48 ID7
seq2 55 66 ID7

seq3 27 40 ID9
```

Adds a new line if last field change from previous line.

If you like to get rid of blanks at the end of the lines use this:

```
awk '{$1=$1;print $0($4!=f?"":RS)} {f=$4}' file
```

The  `$1=$1` recreates the line and removes all trailing spaces and uses default FS between each field.